# How to show an unknown list of variables and their values, if possible

Tags: variables, openedge, progress-4gl

As mentioned before in [some questions with "Progress-4GL" and "OpenEdge" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4279155%20%5Bprogress-4gl%5D%20%5Bopenedge%5D), I'm working with AppBuilder and Procedure editor. As a result, the debugging possibilities are extremely limited: for knowing the value of a variable, I need to do show them on screen, something like this:

```
MESSAGE "temp1=[" temp1 "], temp2=[" temp2 "]" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

I can also put that information in a logfile, but that's not the main point here.

I would like to write a procedure, which can handle this, something like:

```
PROCEDURE SHOW_VARIABLES_AND_VALUES (INPUT I1, INPUT I2, ...):
  1. <put parameter names and values together inside one string> => """I1="" I1"
  2. <do this for all input parameters (the number is unknown)> => """I1="" I1, ""I2="" I2, ..."
  3. <how to use this (MESSAGE VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX, LOG, ...) there I'll know what to do>
```

Does anybody know how to handle the fist two points (put variable name and value together and handle an unknown number of input parameters)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While not your question, your question does seem to indicate that you have not invoked the debugger (https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvdbg%2Fintroduction.html%23)

Add -debugalert to your shortcut or whatever you use to start your AVM.
Trigger either an error or a MESSAGE VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
Click on 'Help' button - you are shown the stack trace.
Click on 'Debug' button - the debugger starts and you can inspect everything and step through your code.

You can also use the DEBUGGER handle.
You can also connect the debugger to a running AVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUBSTITUTE function.

```
MESSAGE SUBSTITUTE ("temp1=&1 ~ntemp2=&2 ~n temp3=&3",
                    temp1,
                    temp2,
                    temp3) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Unfortunately there is no dynamic access to variables or parameters. So there's no way to automatically add all input parameters to a message string. Also there is no anytype parameter type in the ABL - for user defined functions or procedures. So you'd have to use the STRING() function a lot to convert your input parameters to string as the best fit parameter for everything.

The built in SUBSTITUTE function on the other hand can handle anytype of arguments. So temp1, temp2 and temp3 can actually be variables or parameters of any datatype.

As mentioned in one of my comments on one of your earlier questions: Give the OpenEdge debugger a chance. The debugger outside of Progress Developer studio looks historic. But it does it's job.

Comment: The debugger has been around since the stone age and can be invoked from your code, invoked from a message box or by attaching the stand-alone debugger to your process (pid). Before quantifying something as "extremely limited" try reading the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've decided to use following system (as my request seems to be impossible):

```
  MESSAGE "temp1=[" temp1 "]~n" ~
          "temp2=[" temp2 "]~n" ~
          "temp3=[" temp3 "]~n" ~
          "temp4=[" temp4 "]" ~
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

In order to make it easy to work with, I've found out the following keyboard "shortcut" for the tilde character: <kbd>ALT+0126</kbd>.

As indicated by Stefan, this is far better (no tilde and no shortcut needed):

```
  MESSAGE "temp1=[" temp1 "]" SKIP
          "temp2=[" temp2 "]" SKIP
          "temp3=[" temp3 "]" SKIP
          "temp4=[" temp4 "]" SKIP
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: Note, that in the MESSAGE statement, you could use the SKIP keyword outside of the quotes as well. That would eliminate the need for the tilde at all.

Comment: You're right, but as I'm using the tilde as a way to put similar things on new lines (for readability), I already need the tilde, hence my remark.

Comment: You do not need a tilde to put similar things on new lines, unless you are defining a preprocessor, which you do not show.